# MongoDB how to sort array<String> desc with my requirement?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My documents is as below:

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
```

when i sort with `db.find('user').sort({customs: 1})`, got result (which meet my needs):

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
```

when i sort with `db.find('user').sort({customs: -1})`, got result (which do not meet my need):

```
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
```

my expect is:

```
{
   customs: ['222', '333']  
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222', '333'] 
}
{
   customs: ['111', '222'] 
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code just runs as you expect.

data

```
[
  {
    customs: [
      "111",
      "222"
    ]
  },
  {
    customs: [
      "222",
      "333"
    ]
  },
  {
    customs: [
      "111",
      "222",
      "333"
    ]
  }
]
```

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      customs: -1
    }
  }
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "customs": [
      "222",
      "333"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "customs": [
      "111",
      "222",
      "333"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "customs": [
      "111",
      "222"
    ]
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Zc4A39NE3p)